# Chargify how can get total transactions of between two dates?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, api, chargify

Currently, i am getting only 20 transactions per pages and can be extends only 200 but i need all transaction between that dates no paging.

Or if it possible to get count of transactions.?

How can i archive?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Chargify.NET wrapper?

Comment: I am using ChargifyNet.ChargifyConnect.  and for retrieving transaction i am using "GetTransactionList" method. I also get difficulty to get failed transaction. pls if u have any idea then guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following to retrieve all transactions for a subscription:

```
bool isFinished = false;
int counter = 1;
var results = new Dictionary<int, ITransaction>();
while (!isFinished)
{
    // Get results
    var transactions = chargify.GetTransactionsForSubscription(activeSubscription.SubscriptionID, counter++, 20);

    // Check condition
    if (transactions.Count == 0) { isFinished = true; continue; }

    // Merge results
    transactions.ToList().ForEach(x => results.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
}
```

That should get all the transactions and merge them all into the single dictionary. :) If need to use dates, then just switch the data retrieval line to something like this:

`var transactions = chargify.GetTransactionsForSubscription(activeSubscription.SubscriptionID, counter++, 20, null, int.MinValue, int.MinValue, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Now);` (just switch to your dates).